# Using gpsctl to put a U-blox MAX7 chip in low power mode

Tags: gps, gpsd

I am trying to use the **gpsctl** command to put the U-blox MAX7 chip mounted on a Freescale SABRE Smart Devices Board (SDB) in low power mode.

According to the documentation for the chip.

The CFG-RXM message is what I need to use:

- Header: 0xB5 0X62
- ID: 0x06 0x11
- Length (Bytes): 2
- Payload: 
        Byte offset 0, U1 format, reserved, always set to 8
        Byte offset 1, U1 format, 1pMode, Low power mode 1:Power Save

Using

```
gpsctl –D5 –t “uBlox UBX binary” –e /dev/ttymxc2 –x ‘\x06\x11\x08\x01’
```

I am not noticing any difference.

Is there any way to tell if the chip is receiving the command?  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the software [uCenter](https://www.u-blox.com/de/evaluation-tools-a-software/u-center/u-center.html) from uBlox, to read the current state of the chip.

If you cannot use uCenter, then 
you can write your own software that reads out the CFG State via UBlox binary Protocol (asuming the CFG-RXM is uBlox Binary message)

Comment: The chip is mounted on a SABRE SDB board I the uCenter software seems to work with USB mounted devices

Comment: Then you coud write Software that reads out the CFG.State via UBlock bianry Protocol (asuming the CFG_RXM is uBlox Binary message)